# Find max value and it's address in the List

Tags: c, max, memory-address

C language. This function (Max_Value) is supposed to find max value and it`s address to the next element. I don't know why it doesn't work. It is said 'segmentation fault'.

```
struct List1 *GetAddress(struct List1* Start, int n)
{
    struct List1 *tmp;
    int count;
    if (n < 0 || n >ListLength(Start))
        return NULL;
    tmp = Start;
    for (count = 0; count < n; count++)
        tmp = tmp -> Next;
    return tmp;
}

int Get_Value(struct List1 *Start, int Number_Element)
{
    struct List1 *Buffer;
    Buffer = GetAddress(Start, Number_Element);
    return Buffer -> Info;
}

void Max_Value(struct List1 *Start)
{
    int Max;
    struct List1 *Max_Address;
    int Count;
    int Amount;
    int tmp;
    Amount = Start -> Info;
    Max = Get_Value(Start, Count);
    Max_Address = GetAddress(Start, Count + 1);
    for (Count = 1; Count < Amount; Count++)
    {        
        tmp = Get_Value(Start, Count);
        if (tmp > Max)
        {
            Max = tmp;
            Max_Address = GetAddress(Start, Count + 1);        
        }        
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("%d -> %p\n", Max, Max_Address);
}
```

Comment: Use a debugger. It will tell you instantly exactly which line of code triggers the seg fault. If you want further help here please provide a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). That is, include the code that sets up the list and that calls the function being tested.

Comment: In `Max_Value()` you use the uninitialized value of the `Count` variable. I think you need to initialize `Count` to 0.

Comment: Also your `Max_Value()` function is terribly inefficient. You have managed to turn a simple operation that should have O(N) time complexity into one that has O(N^2) time complexity.

Comment: Thank you! Initializing Count as 0 at the beginning helped. Everything works fine now. My gratitude.

Comment: @DimaSidukov no, that was not the only problem in your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending the value `Count`  to `GetAdress` without been initialized, in C when a value is not initialized it gets an unexpected number which exceeds the size of your list. Given this, you're trying to access to outside the bounds of the list, which returns a segmentation fault.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you are using the variable "Count" which has no initial value. Therefore, the initial is a random number.
if the initial value of "Count" is larger than size of List, GetAddress will return null. 
Then Get_Value function will try to access Null->Info, then you got segmentation fault

Answer (score 0):

You have undefined behaviors

For instance  in *Max_Value* you do `Get_Value(Start, Count);` without having initialized `Count`, so very probably

If *GetAddress* is called with the *n*valuing the length of the list you dereference NULL,

> ```
>    if (n < 0 || n >ListLength(Start))
> ```

must be

```
    if (n < 0 || n >= ListLength(Start))
```

In *Get_Value* you do

> ```
> Buffer = GetAddress(Start, Number_Element);
> return Buffer -> Info;
> ```

without checking if *GetAddress* return NULL, so you can dereference NULL again

---

For readability reasons I encourage you to not use capitalized names for the local variables, use that for the types you define and the global variables.

---

Your code is also very complicated for nothing and very slow because you go throw the list several times. A simple way to do is :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct List {
  int info;
  struct List * next;
};

void Max_Value(struct List * l)
{
  if (l == NULL)
    puts("empty list");
  else {
    struct List * pmax = l;
    int max = l->info;

    while ((l = l->next) != NULL) {
      if (l->info > max)
        pmax = l;
    }

    printf("max value %d (at %p), next is %p\n", max, pmax, pmax->next);
    if (pmax->next != NULL)
      printf("value of the next cell %d\n", pmax->next->info);
  }
}

// to help to make a list

struct List * mk(int v, struct List * n)
{
  struct List * l = malloc(sizeof(struct List));

  l->info = v;
  l->next = n;
  return l;
}

// free resources

void del(struct List * l)
{
  while (l) {
    struct List * n = l->next;

    free(l);
    l = n;
  }
}

int main()
{
  struct List * l;

  l = mk(3, mk(1, mk(4, mk(2, NULL))));
  Max_Value(l);
  del(l);

  l = mk(3, mk(1, mk(4, mk(22, NULL))));
  Max_Value(l);
  del(l);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @DimaSidukov I edited my answer with a proposal, as you can see *Max_Value* does need to have a long definition and all can be done in it without the help of other functions making your code complicated and slow